# Use Future with MaterialApp.router in main.dart

Tags: firebase, flutter

**SITUATION:** I'm trying to set up firebase with my flutter project by following this [guide by the firebase team.](https://youtu.be/EXp0gq9kGxI?t=909)

**PROBLEM:** In the final steps of the guide, a FutureBuilder widget is passed to the 'home' property of a MaterialApp widget. However, MaterialApp.router does not have a 'home' property, so I am struggling to complete the set-up (am new to flutter :-)).

Any thoughts on how to solve this problem?

```
// Import libraries
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

// Import custom widgets
import 'views/landing_page.dart';
import 'views/info_page.dart';


// Initiate the app
Future<void> main() async {
  // Ensure all services are loaded before app is started
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  // Run the app
  runApp(MyApp());
}


// Define the MyApp widget
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final Future<FirebaseApp> _fbApp = Firebase.initializeApp();

  // Build the website
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      routeInformationParser: _router.routeInformationParser,
      routerDelegate: _router.routerDelegate,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }

  // Declare routing information
  final _router = GoRouter(
    routes: [
      GoRoute(
        path: '/',
        builder: (context, state) => const LandingPage(),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: '/info',
        builder: (context, state) => const InfoPage(),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

Comment: I think you can try on `routerDelegate`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

figured this one out on my own. I did indeed need to just wrap the entire MaterialApp in a Futurebuilder

```js
// Import libraries
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

// Import custom widgets
import 'views/landing_page.dart';
import 'views/info_page.dart';


// Initiate the app
Future<void> main() async {
  // Ensure all services are loaded before app is started
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  // Run the app
  runApp(MyApp());
}


// Define the MyApp widget
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final Future<FirebaseApp> _initializedApp = Firebase.initializeApp();

  // Build the website
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return return FutureBuilder(
      future: _initializedApp,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return const Text('Something went wrong. Please try reloading!');
        } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return MaterialApp.router(
            routeInformationParser: _router.routeInformationParser,
            routerDelegate: _router.routerDelegate,
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          );
        } else {
          return const Center(
            child:  SizedBox(
              height: 150,
              width: 150,
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );

  // Declare routing information
  final _router = GoRouter(
    routes: [
      GoRoute(
        path: '/',
        builder: (context, state) => const LandingPage(),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: '/info',
        builder: (context, state) => const InfoPage(),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and above is how i handle it

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

Future<void> startingServices() async {
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 40));
}

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      routerConfig: router,
    );
  }
}

class BeforeHome extends StatelessWidget {
  const BeforeHome({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: startingServices(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return const Home();
        } else {
          return const SplashSreen();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Material(
      child: Text("Home"),
    );
  }
}

class SplashSreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SplashSreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return Material(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: const <Widget>[
          Text(
            "Initialization...",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 32,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

final router = GoRouter(
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
        path: '/',
        builder: (context, state) => const BeforeHome(),
        routes: [
          GoRoute(
            path: 'home',
            builder: (context, state) => const Home(),
          )
        ])
  ],
);
```